# Render Graphics in browser

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl, jmonkeyengine

We have one client server application developed in Java. For the client we are using swing components. Inside the swing canvas, we are rendering graphics using jmonkeyengine.

Our question is how we can move our client from swing to browser. Is there any technology through which we can show the client in browser or render the graphics in browser?

Comment: *"..from swing to browser.."*  So ..you've never heard of a `JApplet`?  Are you referring to embedding the entire app. into the browser or just the final output of the app.?

Comment: Andrew is right, turn your application into an applet and follow these instructions: http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/sdk:application_deployment#browser_applet If you need much help, please indicate which version of JMonkeyEngine, which version of JogAmp (JOGL, JOAL, JOCL) and which JME canvas you use.

Comment: Thanks for the respose. We had thought about the applet but it didn't match with out application. Can WebGL provide the same behaviour as openGL? Can it be used with jmonkeyengine? We are using jme2.

Comment: Why didn't it match with your application? If you want to use Java in the web browser, there is currently no other solution than applets (or JSP but it has nothing to do with 3D rendering). JMonkeyEngine 2 supports JOGL, JMonkeyEngine 3 too (my unofficial renderer works correctly as far as I know). WebGL and JOGL are completely different technologies and WebGL isn't the panacea as I explained here: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/webgl-une-technologie-prometteuse-qui-doit-encore-faire-ses-preuves-webgl-a-promising-technology-that-has-yet-to-prove-itself/

Comment: @user3759750 There are a very few libraries that allow to write your code in Java and deploy it in the web browser without using the Java plugin. Maybe have a look at LibGDX, it has a JOGL backend and a GWT backend. Sorry for the late reply. WebGL is a Javascript API allowing to use OpenGL ES 2 and later in the web browser whereas JogAmp is a set of Java bindings for OpenGL, OpenGL-ES, OpenAL and OpenCL.